# How to apply the Four Colour theorem on GeoJSON feature collection with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mathematical-optimization, color-theory

Imagine you have a GeoJSON feature collection of adjacent colored polygons presented in a Leaflet map; in the present case the parishes of the city of Lisbon

**Run the snippet to see the map**

```js
fetch('https://geoapi.pt/municipio/lisboa/freguesias?json=1').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
  const geojsons = data.geojsons
  
  var map = L.map('map')

  const bbox = geojsons.municipio.bbox
  const corner1 = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0])
  const corner2 = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2])
  const bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2)
  map.fitBounds(bounds)
  
  L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map)

  // feature collection
  const parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: geojsons.freguesias
  }

  // need this for color pallete
  const numberOfParishes = parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection.features.length
  parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection.features.forEach((parish, index) => {
    parish.properties.index = index
  })

  L.geoJson(parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection, {
    style
  }).addTo(map)

  function style (feature) {
    return {
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'white',
      dashArray: '3',
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.index, numberOfParishes)
    }
  }

})

// get random color
function getColor (index, size) {
  const colors = {
    3: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada'],
    4: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072'],
    5: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3'],
    6: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462'],
    7: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69'],
    8: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5'],
    9: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9'],
    10: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'],
    11: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#ccebc5'],
    12: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#ccebc5', '#ffed6f']
  }

  if (size < 3) {
    return colors[3][index]
  } else if (size <= 12) {
    return colors[size][index]
  } else {
    return colors[12][index % 12]
  }
}
```

```css
#map { height: 220px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

How would you apply the Four Colour theorem or any suitable algorithm to avoid adjacent polygons to have the same color?

Comment: See https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/01/coloring-us-county-map.html for an example.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I'd rather use [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/welsh-powell-graph-colouring-algorithm/), but I need to implement it ;)

Comment: I don't. That is a greedy heuristic (ie it finds good solutions but not -- in general -- optimal ones).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TomazicM from [other stack exchange site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/458234/182228), I could implement it. Please upvote him accordingly, not me, I just post here for users that just arrive here to know and since SO allows snippet insertion, thus you can see it working live.

It makes use of another library, named [TopoJSON](https://github.com/topojson/topojson)

```js
const colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#ccebc5', '#ffed6f']

function style (feature) {
  return {
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    fillColor: colors[feature.properties.colorIndex]
  }
} 

fetch('https://geoapi.pt/municipio/lisboa/freguesias?json=1').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
  const geojsons = data.geojsons
  
  var map = L.map('map')

  const bbox = geojsons.municipio.bbox
  const corner1 = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0])
  const corner2 = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2])
  const bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2)
  map.fitBounds(bounds)
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map)

  // feature collection
  const parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: geojsons.freguesias
  }

var topoJSON = topojson.topology([parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection], 1e4);

  var neighbors = topojson.neighbors(topoJSON.objects[0].geometries);
  
  var featureColors = [];
  parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection.features.forEach((parish, index) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      var found = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < neighbors[index].length; j++) {
        if (featureColors[neighbors[index][j]] == i) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) break;
    }
    featureColors[index] = i;
    parish.properties.colorIndex = i;
  });

  L.geoJson(parishesGeoJsonFeatureCollection, {
    style
  }).addTo(map)
})
```

```css
#map { height: 220px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```